# Смена одного div на другой

Tags: jquery

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появлялся один div, а при нажатии на вторую кнопку вместо этого появлялся другой?

Comment: @Radnk, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: rtfm методы fadeIn fadeOut, Hide и другие.

Answer (score 2):

Задай каждому из `div` по уникальному `id` и при нажатии на кнопку меняй свойство `display` для каждого из слоёв